# How to play next audio using VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I have two textbox. I want to play audio 1 to audio 4 then it will play audio1, audio2, audio3 and audio4

```
Sub play()

For i As integer = textbox1.Text To textbox2.Text
My.Computer.Audio.Play("D:\Audio\audio1", AudioPlayMode.Background)
```

(goo.gl/nHGxMS)

still can't resolve

Comment: Not enough information: what are the files called? is there a limited amount of tracks? etc

Comment: I guess the first problem you encountered is that you need to convert `textbox1.Text` and `textbox2.Text` values to Integer. Next, look into [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a path with your For-Loop variable `i`.

Comment: Get to know how to use [**`For` loops**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For loop is from integer value in textbox1.Text To integer value in textbox2.Text. So convert the values in textbox from string to Integer. Later you can add validations for the values. You may like to check if value is greater than 0, less than 5, etc.
2. For loop is playing only 1 file 4 times in background. So, change the file name in the for loop so that it can play different song file in next iteration.
3. AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete (instead of AudioPlayMode.Background) should be used to wait for the song to complete and then proceed with next iteration.

Try below code.

```
Sub play()

    Dim fromValue As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(textbox1.Text, fromValue) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Not an integer")
        Return
    End If

    Dim toValue As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(textbox2.Text, toValue) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Not an integer")
        Return
    End If

    For i As Integer = fromValue To toValue
        My.Computer.Audio.Play("D:\Audio\audio" & i.ToString, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    Next

End Sub
```